# merging many rows into one row using a common field

Tags: perl, array-merge

I have a file like below.

```
1111|p1
1111|p2
1111|p3
1111|p4
1111|p5
1111|p6
2222|p1
2222|p2
```

and so on ..

one person (1111) can have one product per row.

I need output like below

```
1111|row1|p1|p2|p3|p4|p5
1111|row2|p6
2222|p1|p2 
3333|p1|p2|p3
```

so for one row only upto p5 is allowed, remaining should come in row2. 
please help me get a output this way in Perl.

Comment: what if a "1111|p7" appears after some 2222s?  Does it get merged with the others or not?  If it does, can the output be sorted or should it be in order of a product's first appearance in the file?

Comment: is that "row1" and "row2" literally what you want?

Comment: row1 and row2 can be any thing, its just to count the row number per person. and all the numbers are sorted, so 1111 doesn't appear later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a hash of arrays to store the products for each person:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my %owns;
while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    my ($person, $product) = split /\|/;
    push @{ $owns{$person} }, $product;
}

for my $person (keys %owns) {
    my @products = @{ $owns{$person} };
    if (@products > 5) {
        my $row = 1;
        while (@products) {
            my @five = splice @products, 0, 5;
            print join '|', $person, "row$row", @five;
            print "\n";
            $row++;
        }
    } else {
        print join '|', $person, @products;
        print "\n";
    }
}


__DATA__
1111|p1
1111|p2
1111|p3
1111|p4
1111|p5
1111|p6
2222|p1
2222|p2
```

Comment: or, idiomatically, `for (my $row = 1; @products; ++$row) {`

Comment: @ysth, `while`-solutions seems more organic to me, the intent is so clear.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is worse than programmers trying to be clever.

However, the following uses a regular expression to do the same filter:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $data = do {local $/; <DATA>};

$data =~ s{^((\d+)\|.*\n(?:\2\|.*\n)+)}{
    my ($whole, $header) = ($1, $2);
    my @nums = map {/\|(.*)/} split "\n", $whole;
    my $return = '';
    if (@nums > 5) {
        for (my $i = 1; @nums; $i++) {
            $return .= join('|', $header, "row$i", splice @nums, 0, 5) . "\n";
        }
    } else {
        $return = join('|', $header, @nums) . "\n";
    }
    $return;
}emg;

print $data;

__DATA__
1111|p1
1111|p2
1111|p3
1111|p4
1111|p5
1111|p6
2222|p1
2222|p2
```

Outputs:

```
1111|row1|p1|p2|p3|p4|p5
1111|row2|p6
2222|p1|p2
```